# Find exact number match in array?

Tags: javascript

checkArray is: [10 item a, 11 item b, 25 item c]

Now I have a number say 25, I want to check if in array then return that array.
works but if I test 1, it matches the 10 item.

So do I need to test for a full number match? Or parse array string till space then test for exact match???

```
for (var i=0; i < checkArray.length; i++) {

    var regexp = item;

    if ( checkArray[i].match(regexp)) {   
        return checkArray[i];
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're doing comparison with regex? Why not use `===` or `==`?

Comment: Depends, can you add the array to the code or put it all in a fiddle? Need to know if you are doing partial matches, type unsafe comparison etc.

Comment: If you always have a number at the beginning followed by  text you can also just parseInt and it will pull the number out for you. var n = parseInt("10 item a");console.log(n);

Comment: Mike Cheel, worked perfect thank you so much. :) nice appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If the format of strings in the array is strict, and it always starts with a number followed by space, then set your regex accordingly:

```
var checkArray =  ["10 item a", "11 item b", "25 item c"];
var item = 10;    
var regexp = '^' + item + '\ ';

for (var i=0; i < checkArray.length; i++) {        
    if ( checkArray[i].match(regexp)) {   
        return checkArray[i];
    }    
}
```

Comment: see above... function inArray2(checkArray, item) {
 for (var i=0; i < checkArray.length; i++) {
            var n = parseInt(checkArray[i])      // pull out number
        if ( n == item) {      
            return checkArray[i];
         }
  }
 return false;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array contains strings that are always of the same format and that you can use ECMA5 (though shims are available), then you could possibly do this.

Javascript

```
function hasElementStarting(array, number) {
    var val = false;

    array.some(function (element) {
        if(element.split(' ').shift() === number.toString()) {
            val = element;
        }

        return val;
    });

    return val;
}

var checkArray = ["10 item a", "11 item b", "25 item c"],
    item = 10;

console.log(hasElementStarting(checkArray, item));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/1n2f4qcb/)